# Merging multiple csv into one Excel file without having Excel installed

Tags: powershell

I am working on a script where I am trying to merge multiple csv into a single Excel file with csv filename as different sheet.

All the csv files have the same number of columns and name.

I don't have Excel installed on my server, so I've written this code using `ImportExcel`:

```
#Install-Module ImportExcel -scope CurrentUser
$path="C:\Scripts" #target folder
cd $path;
$csvs = Get-ChildItem .\* -Include *.csv
$csvCount = $csvs.Count
Write-Host "Detected the following CSV files: ($csvCount)"
foreach ($csv in $csvs) {
    Write-Host " -"$csv.Name
}

$excelFileName = $path + "\" + $(get-date -f yyyyMMdd) + "_combined-data.xlsx"
Write-Host "Creating: $excelFileName"

foreach ($csv in $csvs) {
    $csvPath = $path + $csv.Name
    $worksheetName = $csv.Name.Replace(".csv","")
    Write-Host " - Adding $worksheetName to $excelFileName"
    Import-Csv -Path $csvPath | Export-Excel -Path $excelFileName -WorkSheetname $worksheetName
```

The script is taking time and executing without any issue but the Excel sheet is not being generated.

Please can you help me find and fix the issue in this script?

Comment: **[1]** `$csvPath = $path + $csv.Name` is missing the backslash. Use `Join-Path` instead. **[2]** `$worksheetName = $csv.Name.Replace(".csv","")` --> `$worksheetName = $csv.BaseName`, but remember that Microsoft Excel does not allow worksheet name longer than 31 characters. **[3]** Change `$csvs = Get-ChildItem .\* -Include *.csv` to `$csvs = Get-ChildItem .\* -Filter '*.csv' -File`

Comment: is the excel FILE not being created or is the file being created but the sheet you want is not there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a worksheet per CSV to your Excel file the code should look something like this:

```sh
$path = "D:\Testing"
$csvs = Get-ChildItem $path -Filter *.csv
$excelFileName = Join-Path $path -ChildPath "$(Get-Date -f yyyyMMdd)_combined-data.xlsx"

foreach ($csv in $csvs)
{
    $props = @{
        WorksheetName = $csv.BaseName
        Path = $excelFileName
    }

    Import-Csv -Path $csv |
    Export-Excel @props
}
```

---

If you want to do all in memory (more efficient than the example above), it's a bit more complicated. You **need** to use `-PassThru`.

Note, this works on `ImportExcel 7.1.2`, make sure you have the last up to date version.

```sh
$path = "D:\Testing"
$csvs = Get-ChildItem $path -Filter *.csv
$excelFileName = Join-Path $path -ChildPath "$(Get-Date -f yyyyMMdd)_combined-data.xlsx"

foreach ($csv in $csvs)
{
    $content = Import-Csv -Path $csv

    $props = @{
        WorksheetName = $csv.BaseName
        PassThru = $true
        InputObject = $content
    }

    if(-not $xlsx)
    {
        $props.Path = $excelFileName
        $xlsx = Export-Excel @props

        continue
    }

    $props.ExcelPackage = $xlsx
    Export-Excel @props > $null
}

Close-ExcelPackage $xlsx
```

---

If you want **all CSV** files on the same worksheet, **assuming they all have the same headers**:

```sh
$path = "D:\Testing"
$csvs = Get-ChildItem $path -Filter *.csv
$excelFileName = Join-Path $path -ChildPath "$(Get-Date -f yyyyMMdd)_combined-data.xlsx"

Import-Csv -Path $csvs |
Export-Excel -WorksheetName 'Merged' -Path $excelFileName
```